# Template Razor ASP Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Tengo dos páginas Razor, una de create y otra de List. Me gustaria que en la página de List tambien tener el código de Create pero si meto todo ahi mucho código y no me gusta, me gustaria en la página llamarlo como un @render template o algo asi, ¿ es posible?

Comment: pero que llevas hasta ahora, cual es tu pregunta en especifico?

Comment: es un proyecto asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 0):

Para separar las vistas puedes usar el

```
@Html.Partial()
```

[Partial View](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/partial-view-in-asp.net-mvc)

analiza el articulo y veras como en el view puede incluir el codigo de la view partial usando

```
@Html.Partial("nombreViewPartial")
```

asi puede separar el html para que sea mas mantenible

Comment: he probado <partial name="_MainPartial" />, lo que me comentaste no me funcionaba, gracias de todas formas, un saludo

Comment: pero ese tag html de partial solo aplica si usas `asp.net core`, estas usando esa version ? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2